# MSTest abstract class

Tags: c#, testing, mstest

Normally it is not possible to instantiate an abstract class directly but for the purposes of testing many testing frameworks provide functionality to achieve this. Is it possible to test abstract classes using MSTest?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is:

- Make a test implementation of your class and write your test on that implementation
- Use a mocking framework like Microsoft Fakes, this will generate a implementation of your abstract class under test on which you can write your tests.

Comment: Can Microsoft Fakes' Stubs functionality handle an abstract class?

Comment: Yes, it creates a stub for a abstract class.